# Specifying a source in puppet doesn't seem to work

Tags: yum, puppet, rpm

I have been attempting to create a manifest for installing postgres 9.1 using puppet on a Centos 5 server. I have been trying to adapt the instructions at http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation in order to achieve this and when I go through a manual process, I have been able to.

It would seem to me therefore that a puppet manifest containing

```
package { 'postgresql91-server':
  ensure => installed,
  source => 'http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-5-x86_64/pgdg-centos91-9.1-4.noarch.rpm'
}
```

however on attempting to apply this manifest I get

```
err: /Stage[main]//Package[postgresql91-server]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Could not find package postgresql91-server
```

Any expert puppeteers out there able to help me?

Comment: Removed postgresql tag - this question applies to any package with dependencies not available in a local repository. +1 for including exact error message text, commands and (some) version numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the repo to yum (using puppet of course), then specify the repo resource as a dependency of the package. This will make upgrading easier later on. See the puppet docs on [yum repos](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#yumrepo) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to all help from Steve and Paul. The final code that I have used is

```
yumrepo { "postgres":
  baseurl => "http://yum.postgesql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-5x86_64/",
  descr => "Postgres 9.1 repository",
  enabled => 1,
  gpgcheck => 1
}

package { 'postgresql91-server' :
  ensure => installed,
}
```

This does the trick!

Comment: gpgcheck => 0 isn't the best idea if you can avoid that.  Are postgresql really releasing unsigned RPMs in their yumrepo?

Comment: I'll make a change to gpgcheck => 1 as they do sign their rpms. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

According to https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/package.html, source is dependent upon the underlying package provider supporting it.  To my knowledge, yum doesn't allow arbitrary URLs - you must specify a repo (as Steve Wills mentioned).

You might be able to work around this by specifying 'provider => "rpm"' for just this package resource, but i've not tried this myself.

Comment: Yum does allow arbitrary URLs, but it cannot work out that the URL is part of a yum respository and fetch dependencies from the same repository. You can install from a URL to an RPM only if you have a locally defined repo that contains all the dependencies or the dependencies of the package are already installed.

Comment: That is if the RPM is actually in a repo.  YUM does not require it to be in a repo, it can even install from a local directory.    The problem is Puppet 'assumes' it is part of a repo, even when it isn't!